# CSV file converter using VBA error when saved

Tags: vba, excel, save

The codes below is for CSV file converter into excel tabled form.

The problem is that when the whole workbook is being saved (MACRO-ENABLED EXCEL FORM), the problem begins. When the workbook is NEW and when I copy pasted the program and run it without saving it, the program runs well but after saving it for later use, the program wont do its job. There are no error messages when I run it. It just doesn't do what it does.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFile()
Dim sPath As String
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim FilePath As String

'change the display name of the open file dialog
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Title = _
    "CSV File Opener"

'Remove all other filters
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear

'Add a custom filter
Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add( _
    "CSV Files Only", "*.csv")

'only allow the user to select one file
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then

    'get the file path selected by the user
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    Cells(7, 7) = strPath
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong CSV File. Please Choose Again"

End If
'Below we assume that the file, csvtest.csv,
'is in the same folder as the workbook. If
'you want something more flexible, you can
'use Application.GetOpenFilename to get a
'file open dialogue that returns the name
'of the selected file.
'On the page Fast text file import
'I show how to do that - just replace the
'file pattern "txt" with "csv".
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & strPath

'Procedure call. Semicolon is defined as separator,
'and data is to be inserted on "Sheet2".
'Of course you could also read the separator
'and sheet name from the worksheet or an input
'box. There are several options.
copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet sPath, ";", "Sheet2"

End Sub
'**************************************************************
Private Sub copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, parSheetName As String)

Dim Data As Variant  'Array for the file values

'Function call - the file is read into the array
Data = getDataFromFile(parFileName, parDelimiter)

'If the array isn't empty it is inserted into
'the sheet in one swift operation.
If Not isArrayEmpty(Data) Then
  'If you want to operate directly on the array,
  'you can leave out the following lines.
  With Sheets(parSheetName)
    'Delete any old content
    .Cells.ClearContents
    'A range gets the same dimensions as the array
    'and the array values are inserted in one operation.
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
  End With
End If

End Sub

    Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns False if not an array or a dynamic array
'that hasn't been initialised (ReDim) or
'deleted (Erase).

If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
On Error Resume Next
If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then
   isArrayEmpty = True
   Exit Function
Else
   isArrayEmpty = False
End If

End Function
'**************************************************************
Private Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, _
parDelimiter As String, _
Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is the delimited file (csv, txt ...)
'parDelimiter is the separator, e.g. semicolon.
'The function returns an empty array, if the file
'is empty or cannot be opened.
'Number of columns is based on the line with most
'columns and not the first line.
'parExcludeCharacter: Some csv files have strings in
'quotations marks ("ABC"), and if parExcludeCharacter = """"
'quotation marks are removed.

Dim locLinesList() As Variant 'Array
Dim locData As Variant        'Array
Dim i As Long                 'Counter
Dim j As Long                 'Counter
Dim locNumRows As Long        'Nb of rows
Dim locNumCols As Long        'Nb of columns
Dim fso As Variant            'File system object
Dim ts As Variant             'File variable
Const REDIM_STEP = 10000      'Constant

'If this fails you need to reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
'You select this in "Tools" (VBA editor menu).
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error GoTo error_open_file
'Sets ts = the file
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
On Error GoTo unhandled_error

'Initialise the array
ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
i = 0
'Loops through the file, counts the number of lines (rows)
'and finds the highest number of columns.
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
  'If the row number Mod 10000 = 0
  'we redimension the array.
  If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve locLinesList _
    (1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
  End If
  locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
  j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'Nb of columns in present row
  'If the number of columns is then highest so far.
  'the new number is saved.
  If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
  i = i + 1
Loop

ts.Close 'Close file

locNumRows = i

'If number of rows is zero
If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function

ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

'Copies the file values into an array.
'If parExcludeCharacter has a value,
'the characters are removed.
If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then
  For i = 1 To locNumRows
    For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
      If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
        If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = _
          Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)
        Else
          locLinesList(i)(j) = _
          Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
      ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
        locLinesList(i)(j) = _
        Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
      End If
      locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
    Next j
  Next i
Else
  For i = 1 To locNumRows
    For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
      locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
    Next j
  Next i
End If

getDataFromFile = locData

Exit Function

error_open_file:  'Returns empty Variant
unhandled_error:  'Returns empty Variant

End Function
```

Comment: your sPath value is double path value, 1st is your workbook self, 2nd path is csv path.. sPath variable should be `sPath = strPath` because file to try opened is jus csv file. so just edit `sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & strPath` to `sPath = strPath`

Comment: @pidel - make that an answer so it can be accepted - that will help users find it more easily.

Comment: i will make it an answer.. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sPath value is double path value, 1st path is your workbook self, 2nd path is csv path.. sPath variable should be `sPath = strPath` because file to try opened is just csv file. before you save your workbook, the sPath is ok because workbook path is empty and value of sPath just csv path, after saving workbook into file, workbook has pathfile.
so just `edit sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & strPath` to `sPath = strPath`